# getView return wrong value from getItemViewType

Tags: android, view, getview

I've been having this problem for few days,it seems like the return value i get from "getItemViewType" did not passed to "getView" correctly.

When i debugged it, it return first "final_value" then supposedly should go to "getView" but it didnt, only proceed to "getView" after the second return final value, which im not sure why, maybe my design is wrong, im not sure. please help, below is my code:

```
public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<chatMessageObject> {

private static final String TAG = "TESTING";
private static final int TYPE1= 1;
private static final int TYPE2= 2;
private static final int TYPE3= 3;
private static final int TYPE4= 4;
private static final int TYPE5= 5;
private static List<String> date_list = new ArrayList<>();


private int mLayoutResource, type;
private Context mContext;
private String id, name;

public myListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<myObject> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResource = resource;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    TextView name,id;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int final_value = 0;
    id = getItem(position).get_id();
    name = getItem(position).get_name();

    if (!Objects.equals(id, name)) {
        if (Objects.equals(getItem(position).getName().trim(), "Test")) {
            final_value = TYPE1;
        }
        else if (!date_list.contains(getItem(position).getDate().substring(0,10))) {
            date_list.add(getItem(position).getDate().substring(0,10));
            final_value = TYPE2;
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED...");
            final_value = TYPE3;
        }
    } else {
        if (Objects.equals(getItem(position).getName().trim(), "Test")) {
            final_value = TYPE1;
        }
        else if (!date_list.contains(getItem(position).getDate().substring(0,10))) {
            date_list.add(getItem(position).getDate().substring(0,10));
            final_value = TYPE4;
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT...");
            final_value = TYPE5;
        }
    }
        return final_value;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        Log.d(TAG,"type = " + type);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE1;
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, parent, false);
                    holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_type1);
                    holder.id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_type1);
                    break;
                case TYPE2;:
                    Log.d(TAG,"TYPE2");
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test2, parent, false);
                    holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_type2);
                    holder.id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_type2);
                    break;
                case TYPE3;
        Log.d(TAG,"TYPE3");
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test3, parent, false);
                    holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_type3);
                    holder.id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_type3);
                    break;

                case TYPE4;
        Log.d(TAG,"TYPE4");
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test4, parent, false);
                    holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_type4);
                    holder.id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_type4);
                    break;

                case TYPE5;
                    Log.d(TAG,"TYPE5");
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test5, parent, false);
                    holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_type5);
                    holder.id = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_type5);
                    break;

            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

    holder.name.setText("TEST NAME");
            holder.id.setText("ID");



        return convertView;

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by wrong value ? do you mean wrong position ?

Comment: suppose when return TYPE2 in getItemViewType, i should get TYPE2 also in getView right? i mean thats the sequence right? but it didnt went that way

Comment: okay what do you want then

Comment: post debug log.

Comment: thats what i want, after getting return value lets say TYPE2 in getItemViewType, that return value should also appear the same in getView, BUT seems like when i got the first return value, it didnt went directly to getView, it REPEAT getItemViewType instead then return another value, so i missed the first value. thats my problem.

Comment: in the debug log after finished getItemViewType, it went to AbsListView class and state that mTransientStateViewsById = null
mTransientStateViews = null, only for the first return value, the second return value didnt go to this class, it went to getView directly